# Confusion in dynamic variable access in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Below is the code block, I am using.

```
<cfset variables.test1 = 'interface.temp1'>
<cfset variables.test2 = 'interface.temp2'>
<cfset variables.test3 = 'variables.' & variables.test2>
<cfset variables["#variables.test1#"] = 23>
<cfset "#variables.test3#" = 50>

<cfdump var="#variables#">
<cfdump var="#variables['interface.temp1']#">
```

The attached image describes the output, I am getting.
The first cfdump displays the "interface.temp1" value as "undefined" and in the second cfdump it is displaying the value as "23". If you also look at the first cfdump, it is displaying all the variables in VARIABLES scope but there is no variable having the value as "23", then in the second cfdump from where is it getting the value as "23"?

Please help me to know the cause behind this.

[image]

Comment: The output you posted above is not the output I get when I run that code on CF9. It all works as expected for me (try it on cflive.net)

Comment: What version of CF are you running?

Comment: @Michael Giovanni Pumo, I am using CF9

Comment: @Adam Cameron, I also checked this is cflive.net and found that the output is different, but in my local machine I am getting the output I have posted. What could be cause behind this?

Comment: Running this on my CF 9 instance gives the same as the question. Same version as cflive as well :/

Comment: This appears to be an issue on version 9.0.1, which is what I am running and I see the same thing as the OP.  I tested this on CFLive as well. The version of Railo on CFLive is 10,0,0,0 and the version of ACF on CFLive is 9,0,2,282541. Both of those work correctly. I tested on ACF version 9,0,1,274733 and it fails as the OP found.

Comment: There should be no difference between 9.0.1 and 9.0.2 (aside from Verity being dropped). Is your 9.0.1 fully hotfixed?

Comment: Yes. I have installed hotfix 4 (chf9010004.jar) and the latest patches (hf901-00011.jar). In case it matters I am also running JVM 1.7.0_51

Comment: I just tested this on [trycf.com](http://trycf.com) as well. It is running ACF version 10,0,12,286680 and it failed as well.

Comment: I am running 9.0.2 and it is failing.

Comment: Confirmed: I'm seeing the OP's behaviour on my local install of CF9.0.1 (and slightly different wrong behaviour on CF11)

Answer (score 2):

I've cracked it. I write it up fully on my blog: "[Odd behaviour with struct keys with dots in their names](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/04/odd-behaviour-with-struct-keys-with.html)".

Basically once you have a substruct called `interface`, which is - as @Leigh said - created by this:

```
<cfset "#variables.test3#" = 50>
```

Then ColdFusion (and, fwiw, Railo), get confused when trying to resolve struct keys that are prefixed with `interface.`: it sees those references as references to keys within the `interface` sub struct, rather than simply key names.

If you don't have that line of code above, then CF's able to see the dotted-key-named value just fine.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That is an interesting one. I typically use array notation whenever variable names veer from the straight and narrow (alpha/numeric/underscore), so I have not run into that one. Honestly, I am not sure the expression `st.prefix.key2` *should* work. Allowing that syntax introduces ambiguity, because it would be near impossible to differentiate between a simple key named `prefix.key2` and a structure named `prefix`, containing `key2`. ie `st['prefix.key2'] and st = {prefix={key2="aaa"}}`